# understanding p-channel MOSFET unexpected behavior

Tags: mosfet, p-channel

I'm fairly inexperienced and while I have an understanding of classic npn and pnp transistors, I'm shaky when it comes to MOSFETs.

I'm looking for an element to act as a switch. This element would be normally ON, when no stimulus is applied. The trigger needs to be a positive voltage, and is intended to turn OFF the element (open the circuit).
After a bit of searching I figured that a P-channel JFET transistor might solve my problem.
There would normally be continuity between Drain and Source, unless I applied a positive voltage to the Gate.

I'm talking about a low power application:

- Drain-source voltage: 5V or less
- Drain-source current: a few
  milliamps are enough
- Gate trigger voltage: 5V or less

Maybe hurriedly, I got a [FQP27P06 MOSFET](https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Components/General/FQP27P06.pdf) and set up a simple test circuit with a LED. I understand this is a MOSFET and not a JFET, but I thought it would work anyway.

I'm using a voltage divider to keep the gate voltage in the specified range (2 to 4V). TBH I don't understand why that's actually specified as a negative voltage: -2 to -4 V.

In my intentions, the LED should always be on unless the button is pressed.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOXsBA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What I'm observing is:

- the LED is normally ON
- when I press the button the LED goes OFF
- when I release the button the LED STAYS OFF. Or maybe it just glows very dimly and then turns OFF again. Sometimes it gets brighter and brighter but never reaches full brightness. This behavior seems to be randomic.
- in order to turn the LED back ON again, I need to short the Gate to ground!

I do not understand what's going on. Can someone please help me out?
Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are disconnecting the gate of a mosfet by not pressing a button - this (due to high input impedance of the mosfet) leads to picking up charges from air (it acts like capacitor - try touching gate and ground/power), and partially turning mosfet on. To overcome this issue - add a high value resistor from Gate to ground - this will keep the mosfet on all the time, and when button is pressed - it will "overwrite" the resistor and turn transistor off as before. Value of added resistor should be in such range, that when button is pressed it will not drop the gate voltage to less than mosfet threshold voltage (or any voltage that is required for exact application)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYhp6Z.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: thank you for the exhaustive explanation! it's much clearer now. And the test circuit works

Comment: There is something else wrong with this circuit: You don;t need R3. It's just wasting energy. But you could add a 560 Ohm resistor between SWI and FPQ gate and make R2 560 ohms too. This will help debouncing the switch.

Comment: @Fredled - what is wrong? I believe, that this works well, but I can breadboard it

Comment: It's wrong because it's useless, It's just a connection between + and -.  Amd you waste with only 1K. Use at least 10K if you really want a connection to ground.

Comment: I didnt touch R3, becauose IT was in orginal schematic (in question) and might be needed by other circuitry (outside schematic). I just added needed pulldown. But in this case You are right - it's useless.

Comment: the transistor is specced to take 2-4V on the gate, so I'm using that voltage divider to get 2.5V. I don't think that the 560+560 would create a voltage drop big enough, would it? (I honestly don't know, how much current would the gate draw).
The energy waste is not an issue, as this whole thing only works on a pulse, a couple times a day. But I suppose that I could make R2 = R3 = 10K

Comment: @Valentino You are not dividing anything with that. Resistor (R3) is on 5V supply, so voltage on it is 5V, R2 is to limit peak current of charging/discharging gate.

Comment: I see, R2 is misplaced in my schematic. it should be between the power supply and R3

Answer (score 2):

The oxide layer in the transistor creates a capacitor with the gate as one plate and the rest of the device as the other.  When you open the switch it's holding enough gate charge to deplete the channel.  Try putting a pull-down resistor between the gate and ground.

Comment: amazing! a 1k resistor got it working nicely :)
thank you very much!

Comment: 1K is too little. Use at least 10K or 33K as suggested in the other answer.

Comment: I understand that now. Initially I tried to use a 15k R and it seemed not to be working, but the reason was simply that its thin legs weren't making contact properly. N00bs' problems :)